# Vaadin Tables - make the empty spaces look stripped

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using several tables in my application, but the thing is if the table is not filled the remaining space stays empty, not stripped as usual. Example:

[image]

Do you  have any idea on that? It looks really ugly if the table is not fully filled.

PS: I don't want to fill it with dummy data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an image that has those row colors and set that image as a CSS background for the white part.

Comment: Is it the only way? Nothing in the API?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no API for that.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause for this issue is Application (PagedTable component) is setting some default/programmer defined pageLength say 25 items per page of the table and if there is only 2 items in that specific page then rest of the 23 rows will empty and will show empty space instead of the data.
So in order to fix this issue we can check actual content of the specific page of the table and then set pagelength programmatically.

We need check and  set pageLenght with change event with page length selected by end user or with default value
    addListener(new PageChangeListener() {
            public void pageChanged(PagedTableChangeEvent event) {
            //added for setting table height accordingly
            if(container.getRealSize() - getPageLength()<0){
                        setPageLength(container.getRealSize());
            }
        }
    });

Moreover we also need to check and set pageLength in the same way with other event like first,previous,page number, next and last navigation changes under pagination functionality.